# Cannot reshape after concatenate in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have a model with a shared encoder that uses Keras's concatenate to get all of the encoded values into a single output for training. Ideally, I would like it to [stack](https://keras.io/backend/#stack) the encoded values.

I couldn't get that to work, due to the same error I'm demonstrating in this problem. But since stack is a backend function, it seemed like a better idea to have my simpler example just use reshape.

Here's my code:

```py
import keras.backend as K
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Input, Reshape, Flatten, concatenate
from keras.optimizers import Adam

input_shape = (28, 28)
output_length = 10

anchor_input = Input(shape=input_shape)
positive_input = Input(shape=input_shape)
negative_input = Input(shape=input_shape)

shared_encoder = Sequential()
shared_encoder.add(Flatten())
shared_encoder.add(Dense(output_length * 2))
shared_encoder.add(Dense(output_length, activation='sigmoid'))
# shared_encoder.add(Lambda(lambda x: K.l2_normalize(x, axis=1)))

anchor_encoded = shared_encoder(anchor_input)
positive_encoded = shared_encoder(positive_input)
negative_encoded = shared_encoder(negative_input)
print("encoded shape", K.int_shape(anchor_encoded)) # (None, 10)

merged_outputs = concatenate([anchor_encoded, positive_encoded, negative_encoded], axis=-1)
print("before reshape", K.int_shape(merged_outputs)) # (None, 30)

# ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (32, 1) for Tensor 'reshape_1_target:0', which has shape '(?, ?, ?)'
merged_outputs = Reshape((3, -1))(merged_outputs)
print("after reshape", K.int_shape(merged_outputs)) # (None, 3, 10)

model = Model(inputs=[anchor_input, positive_input, negative_input], outputs=merged_outputs)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from keras.datasets import mnist
    def dumb_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        return K.mean(y_pred)

    model.compile(loss=dumb_loss, optimizer=Adam())

    (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
    model.fit([x_train, x_train, x_train], y_train)
```

As you can see, the model is pretty simple. The dimensions seem to work. It compiles just fine.

But, when I try to fit it, I'm greeted with

> ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (32, 1) for Tensor 'reshape_1_target:0', which has shape '(?, ?, ?)'

What's going on? Where did the `(32, 1)` shape come from? (I know that 32 is the default batch size, but what is that 1 from?) What can I do to get this Reshape layer to work?

EDIT:

I'm using Tensorflow 1.5. It seems like with fresh installs of Tensorflow of a higher number on a different computer, this runs fine. So now I'm wondering if I've just run into an old bug.

Here is my requirements.txt (a.k.a. `pip freeze`):

```
absl-py==0.7.1
bleach==1.5.0
h5py==2.9.0
html5lib==0.9999999
Keras==2.2.4
Keras-Applications==1.0.8
Keras-Preprocessing==1.1.0
Markdown==3.1.1
numpy==1.16.4
protobuf==3.8.0
PyYAML==5.1.1
scipy==1.3.0
six==1.12.0
tensorflow==1.5.0
tensorflow-tensorboard==1.5.1
Werkzeug==0.15.4
```

Comment: Have you tried substituting `(3, -1)` for `(3, 10)`?

Comment: Try restarting the kernel, i did not get any error running your code. Only change i did was to use `tensorflow.keras` instead of `keras`.

Comment: @KrisR89 if that is the case, my guess is that the issue is that I'm using Tensorflow 1.5

Comment: @Pro Q Yeah, possible. I am on tensorflow 1.13.1

Comment: I have been able to confirm that this code runs on [repl.it](https://repl.it), but I'm still curious if maybe this is a Tensorflow 1.5 bug, so I will edit it but leave it open.